# Maximum value of $xy$

Tags: optimization, integers

> Let's suppose that $x, y$ are positive integers such that
>
> $$x+4y = 40$$
>
> How can we maximize $xy$?

I thought of re-writing $xy$ as follows:

$$xy = \frac{1}{8}\biggr[(x+4y)^2-(x^2+16y^2)\biggr] = \frac{1}{8}\biggr[C^2-(x^2+16y^2)\biggr]$$

We can re-write the term $-(x^2+16y^2)$ so that

$$-(x^2+16y^2) = -((40-4y)^2+16y^2) = -(32y^2-320y+40^2)$$

Which means

$$xy = \frac{1}{8}\biggr[\underbrace{C^2-40^2}_{D}-(32y^2-80y)\biggr] = \frac{1}{8}\biggr[D-\underbrace{32}_{E}(y^2-10y)\biggr] = \frac{1}{8}\biggr[D-E(y^2-10y)\biggr]$$

Therefore keeping $y^2-10y$ as small as possible will maximize $xy$, which happens when $y = 5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x+4y=40$, then $x=40-4y$, therefore
$$xy=y(40-4y)=-4y^2+40y $$
which is a parabola, and has a maximum in its vertex, namely in $y=5$

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can use [AM-GM inequility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality),
$${\frac{x+4y}2\ge\sqrt{4xy}\\40\ge4\sqrt{xy}\\xy\le100}$$

---

Form your approach,
$$xy = \frac{1}{8}\biggr[(x+4y)^2-(x^2+16y^2)\biggr] = \frac{1}{8}\biggr[C^2-(x^2+16y^2)\biggr]$$
Now, we can also use AM-GM inequility,
$$x^2+16y^2\ge8xy$$

$$xy\le\frac{1}{8}\biggr[C^2-8xy\biggr]\implies xy\le\frac{1}{16}C^2$$

$$\therefore \max\{xy\}=\frac{1}{16}C^2=\frac{40^2}{4^2}=10^2$$